# Android: creating a bubble with a pointing corner?

Tags: android, drawable

In most of the well-known chat apps (messenger, WhatsApp...) you notice that they use different kinds of chat bubbles.

**first kind:**

A bubble with 4 rounded corners.

**second kind:**

A bubble with 3 rounded corners and 1 corner pointing outside(represents the beginning of the new conversation).

**My attempt:**

I tried using XML drawable layer list to create the effect of the pointing corner. But it doesn't seem like the best approach.

**My question:**

There aren't enough questions about this issue, so my question is What do these apps use? What is recommended?

Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/bassaer/ChatMessageView

Comment: they use 9 pathc images

Comment: https://github.com/lguipeng/BubbleView

Comment: @NileshRathod no need for third party...any other way? I need full control of how the shape looks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They basically use a 9-patch image as background to their views

try this 
http://tekeye.uk/android/examples/ui/android-9-patch-image-files

also 
https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch.html

Comment: 9 patch seems complicated to be created?

Comment: its not there are tools available to create it , in android studio itself .It would take a little time but its easy. go through the links i mentioned patiently

Comment: for that u need a base PNG image ,then u can convert it to 9-patch

Comment: Are you sure its the best way?

Comment: Can I create the 9 patch in adobe illustrator instead of android studio editor?

Comment: you can create your base PNG using any tool (adobe illustrator or other) then transform them into 9 patch as mentioned above. basically 9 patches will indicate which part of the PNG you'll be using for text

Comment: there are high quality tools available online also for the same , search google and try on what suits you the best,for most cases studio tools does the trick

Comment: @Ak9637 Thanks for your effort and help.

Comment: @A.A Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: anytime !! . 9 patch may seem frustrating at start but eventually you will get hold of it pretty quick

Comment: @Ak9637 does matter what is the size if the base png file is?

Comment: not really , but its always advisable to start with the aspect ratio you would need most commonly

Comment: So in case like messenger what size to draw my png?

Comment: please refer the documentation and link for that , there is a lot to learn before you can decide these factors. These r heavily use - case dependent